# How to change the suffix of a section

Tags: titles, titlesec, section-titles

What I want:

[image]

What I have:

[image]

I know it doesn't look nice but I need it like this. I'm using `titlesec` and `\subsection{A section}` to write this. Thanks!

Comment: Which document class do you employ? Should the formatting apply just to subsection-level headers, or to subsubsection-level headers as well? Please tell us how you employ the `titlesec` package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using `titlesec`, my best suggestion would be to use the runin shape and `\thesubsection` followed by manual linebreak in the last (optional) argument, like this:

For subsections:

```
\titleformat{\subsection}[runin]{\large\bfseries}{}{0pt}{}[\quad {\thesubsection\\[0.5\baselineskip]}]
```

(And if you need something similar for sections...)

```
\titleformat{\section}[runin]{\Large\bfseries}{}{0pt}{}[\quad {\thesection\\[0.5\baselineskip]}]
```

This would probably require tweaking, especially if you have longer titles.

Comment: Thanks! This is the answer I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

Try `\subsection*{A section \quad 2.1}`

Answer (score 0):

Define suitably your section format.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{name=\section}[hang]
 {\Large\bfseries}
 {}
 {0pt}
 {\maketitlewithnumber{\thesection}}
\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}[hang]
 {\Large\bfseries}
 {}
 {0pt}
 {}
\newcommand{\maketitlewithnumber}[2]{#2~#1}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{chapter}{2} % just to match your numbers

\section{A section}

Some text

\section{Another section}

Some text

\end{document}
```

The trick is that the material in the last argument to `\titleformat` gets the section title as an argument, so we can define `\maketitlewithnumber` to swap the two parts.

The `numberless` variant for `\section*` is needed as well.

[image]